# Regular expression extractor not working in Jmeter or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jmeter

As on the image, this is the regular expression I have created to capture the blue highlighted value at the HTML document. But every time, My variable v_PID is retuning null.

Am I doing something wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide "Template" and specify the match [group number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges), something like `$1$` should do the trick for you.

[image]

More information: [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)